# C# Error - Argument Exception was Unhandled

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2013, windowsformsintegration

I am writing a patient booking application, and when I click my button, it's supposed to add 365 days (from today) to my Access file under the column Day1.

Now, it was working before, but now it is giving me an error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 34.

Code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DateTime a = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
  HERE-> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
SourceC:\Users\Kolton\Desktop\Doctor App\Database1.accdb"); <- TO HERE

        conn.Open();

        for (int i = 0; i < 366; i++)
        {
            DateTime b = a.AddDays(i);
            string c = b.ToShortDateString();

            using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Times (Date1) values ('" + c + "')";

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Also, trying to kill two birds with one stone here. As a bonus question, is it possible to make this button delete all the rows under the column (Date1) and then make it add the 365 days to it?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `=` after "Data Source", and you might have to wrap the path with some sort of quotes.

Comment: And please use parameterized queries to prevent from SQL injections

Comment: @gunr2171 I have an = after all "Data Source"''s and doesn't pose a problem. EDIT: I feel stupid, I didn't realize you were referencing that I didn't have one.

Comment: Also, @Sybren I am making this program intentionally for a local machine. It's not going to be used online.

Comment: @gunr2171 Submit an answer so I can mark it as correct. It worked.

Comment: @kolton I'd go with Khurram Ali's answer, it includes the fix for your connection string.

Comment: @kolton I would always use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import this at top

`System.Data.OleDb;`

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 DateTime a = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;

 using(OleDbConnection conn = new
 OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
 Source=C:\Users\Kolton\Desktop\Doctor App\Database1.accdb")) 
 {
        for (int i = 0; i < 366; i++)
        {
            DateTime b = a.AddDays(i);
            string c = b.ToShortDateString();

            using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Times (Date1) values ('" + c + "')";
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
    }
  }
```

1. Set your connection string
2. Import System.Data.OledDB
3. Use Using for connection as well
4. It Would be better if you use parameterize query

Answer (score 0):

To answer your *bonus* question, you can probably just do this with a straight access UPDATE query:

https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Create-and-run-an-update-query-9dddc97c-f17d-43f4-a729-35e5ee1e0514

```
UPDATE table     SET newvalue     WHERE criteria;
```

So the answer would look like this:

```
UPDATE Sample set Field1 = DateAdd('d', 365, Field1)
```

NOTE: I agree with gunr2171 that the equal sign is likely the issue.  Upvoted